# How do I determine what this bitmask code is doing

Tags: bitmask

I am an instructor with very little knowledge in programming but need some help with some common programming questions from a test that I cannot figure out. The question reads:
Refer to line 004; the expression "value & 1" does which of the following?

```
    001 unsigned int bitCount (int value) {
    002 unsigned int count = 0;
    003    while (value > 0) {        //until all bits are zero
    004       if ((value & 1) ==1) {  //check lower bit
    005             count++;
    006       }
    007       value >>1;
    008    }
    009    return count;
    010 }
```

- masks all bits except the lsb
- masks the msb exclusively
- masks all bits except the msb
- masks the lsb exclusively

Answer (score 0):

In C, the `&` operator performs the bitwise AND operation.  In other words, it goes bit-by-bit through the two numbers, and sets the corresponding bit of the answer to 1 only if BOTH of the input bits are 1.

In binary, the number 1 is 000....00001, in other words, it only has a single one in the least significant bit position.  So, when you `&` (AND) with it, everything in the answer will be zero except for possibly that least significant bit position, which will be a 1 only if the other input has a 1 in that position.

Also, in your program, line 007 probably doesn't do what you want.  It looks like you are shifting `value` one bit to the right, but then you aren't saving the result of the shift.  Perhaps you want to write something like `value = value >> 1` so that it actually modifies the `value` variable?